# config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false in Rails 4.2 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Our rails 4.2 app consists of several rails engines with or without gem `'protected_attributes'`. What we find out is that in app's `application.rb`, it has to be:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

Otherwise, any `create/update` can not be carried out because the `params` can not be assigned to instance variable. Our question is that, if there is no gem `protected_attributes`  in rails app, do we still need `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false` in `application.rb`? Is this for Rails 3.x or app with gem `protected_attributes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked through several rails 4 apps I have, none of them contained that config, and when I googled the config name, the `protected_attributes` gem came in the results, so I think you could assume that it's only related to the `protected_attributes` gem and that you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the [protected_attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) gem.

When `whitelist_attributes = true` it [causes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes/blob/cfddd2db3376467e4eed279483ac7b1ee2467d74/lib/protected_attributes/railtie.rb#L12-L14) `attr_accessible(nil)` to be added by default for all models meaning you ca not mass assign any attributes for any models unless it has its own `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected`

This can be seen in an older version of the [README.md](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes/blob/d4d3b54d496c7d72ef199b07d1034912e1674b70/README.md#:%7E:text=explicitly%20whitelist%20or%20blacklist)

As of version 1.1.2 this is now [depreciated](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes/blob/9e96d6e37ef4029036a0af196e7a8a735089617b/CHANGELOG.md#112) and does nothing other than log a [depreciation warning](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes/blob/9e96d6e37ef4029036a0af196e7a8a735089617b/lib/protected_attributes/railtie.rb#L4-L6)

So if you are on a Rails 4+ application and do not have the `protected_attributes` gem then you can safely remove it